# Prevent WebView from loading URL in Android (React Native)

Tags: android, networking, webview, react-native

Currently, [OnShouldStartLoadWithRequest](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html#onshouldstartloadwithrequest) is only supported on iOS. [A PR to add support for this on Android](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/6478) was closed. If a WebView on Android tries to open a custom URL scheme, [the app will crash](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10055) -- which is causing my app to crash as well.

The app I'm working on needs to intercept a WebView attempting to open a custom URL scheme and cancel it before opening that URL (which, on iOS, returning `false` on `OnShouldStartLoadWithRequest` is a great way to do that).

What's the best way to do this on Android?

I want this code to work:

```
        <WebView
            ref={WEBVIEW_REF} 
            source={{uri: INITIAL_URI}}
            onShouldStartLoadWithRequest={this.onShouldStartLoadWithRequest}
            style={{width, height: height - navBarHeight, backgroundColor: "#fff"}}
        />
```

---

```
 onShouldStartLoadWithRequest(navigator) {
    if (navigator.url.indexOf(INTERCEPT_URL) === -1) {
        return true;
    }    
    return false;
  }
```

I'm personally okay with pretty much anything that works -- including modifying `ReactWebViewManager.java` manually. I just need to get this out the door.

Answer (score 22):

You can use the [`onNavigationStateChange`](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.43/docs/webview.html#onnavigationstatechange) property, which will get the same `navigator` object as you get in your function [`onShouldStartLoadWithRequest`](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.43/docs/webview.html#onshouldstartloadwithrequest).

```
 <WebView
        ref={WEBVIEW_REF} 
        source={{uri: INITIAL_URI}}
        onShouldStartLoadWithRequest={this.onShouldStartLoadWithRequest} //for iOS
        onNavigationStateChange ={this.onShouldStartLoadWithRequest} //for Android

        style={{width, height: height - navBarHeight, backgroundColor: "#fff"}}
    />
```

And then in the function

```
onShouldStartLoadWithRequest(navigator) {
    if (navigator.url.indexOf(INTERCEPT_URL) === -1) {
        return true;
    } else {
        this.refs[WEBVIEW_REF].stopLoading(); //Some reference to your WebView to make it stop loading that URL
        return false;
    }    
}
```

I had the same requirement as you, and that's how've I solved it.

Comment: After calling `stopLoading()`, my WebView no longer handles touch events.  If the user clicks a link and it opens in their browser, they may later open my app which still shows the WebView.  If they try to click a different link in that WebView it will not do anything.  Did you encounter this?

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify the scheme, you can add `http` suffix to it so the `WebViewManager` won't try to create an intent with that scheme and try to resolve it.

As you probably saw in `ReactWebViewManager`

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if (url.startsWith("http://") || url.startsWith("https://")) {
        return 
    }
    ...
}
```

If the url starts with http the manager won't treat it as a scheme. I know it's an ugly workaround but hey, it does the job.

Comment: I meet the same issue. You mean code in folder node_modules\react-native\ReactAndroid\src\main\java\com\facebook\react\views\webview\ReactWebViewManager.java?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps although it is late leaving it here if it helps anyone. Try using props **onShouldStartLoadWithRequest** like this

```
<WebView
 source={{uri:'https://stackoverflow.com/'}}
 onShouldStartLoadWithRequest={request => {
  if (request.url.includes('https')) {
      return false;
  } else return true;
 }}
 />
```

Answer (score 0):

Could not find solution that works for android.
There is an open issue with WebView. Here is the link to the issue
`https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/issues/1869`

Answer (score 0):

Adding this:

```
setSupportMultipleWindows={false}
```

Along with `onShouldStartLoadWithRequest` surprisingly works for me.